Did ancient Greco-Roman people think their thoughts/feelings came from spirits or gods?
So I know this question probably sounds a bit odd. But I was told by someone that ancient people believed their thoughts, feelings, and even some of their actions were prompted by spirits or gods, supernatural forces. If, for instance, an ancient Greco-Roman person has a strong thought or emotion, it may be a spirit or unseen being giving them this thought. I heard this idea was from some ancient Roman historians. But not much other information was given.
I'm looking for references. Where does the ancient literature write of this idea, and what does it say?
if you google this (which is really all I can do without aimlessly searching various books, which is the point of me asking here), you'll see that there isn't any answers... This question is specific. So, thats why I ask here. There isn't any preliminary research I could do. Again, the point of the question is so that someone can direct me to what I should even look at. I have no clue

Hi MCW, if you google this (which is really all I can do without aimlessly searching various books, which is the point of me asking here), you'll see that there isn't any answers... This question is specific. So, thats why I ask here. There isn't any preliminary research I could do. Again, the point of the question is so that someone can direct me to what I should even look at. I have no clue. Thanks


understood. Couple of conventions for this site. First, all questions should be supported by preliminary research, even if it is to say - as you have - that you've searched and found nothing.  Second, OP should rarely comment; edit the question to address the issues raised in comments, then flag the comment for deletion. I've moved your comment into the question. Feel free to edit for clarity and then flag my comment(s) for deletion.


I'd say the ancients thought that feelings could come from the gods, but they didn't think that all thoughts did.
The locus classicus for this idea goes back to the Iliad (book 1), wherein Achilles experiences intense anger at Agamemnon, but is restrained from lashing out by Athena. Later on in the Iliad (book 19), Agamemnon denies that his actions, those which angered Achilles, came from his own volition, saying

Zeus, Fate, and the Fury who walks in darkness are to blame, for blinding my judgement that day in the assembly when on my own authority I confiscated Achilles’ prize. What choice did I have? There is a goddess who decides these things, Ate, Zeus’ eldest daughter, blinds us all, accursed as she is. Those tender feet of hers never touch the ground, but pass through men’s minds causing harm, ensnaring this one or another. (19.86-94, trans. Kline).

Agamemnon refuses to take blame for his actions, even as he recognizes the actions originate in his authority. Instead, the gods affect their judgment, basically forcing him to do something that he might otherwise not do.
You see similar ideas in Genesis, where when confronted by Moses, Yahweh "hardened" the pharaoh's heart, making the pharaoh too stubborn to listen to Moses' request.
These stories (and many along these lines) helped fuel Julian Jaynes' The Origin of Consciousness in the Breakdown of the Bicameral Mind, wherein he separates the primitive mind (thoughts come from elsewhere) from that after the discovery of introspective consciousness, in which we recognize that our minds generate thought.
I should note that he argues for the development of consciousness within Greek society: by the fifth century, Greek writers describe characters as having their own thoughts, whereas in the Iliad, thoughts occur or are born from the gods or thumos. So it's not that all Greeks (or any Romans) thought that their thoughts come from the gods, but only in the earliest, primitive part of existence.
The book isn't so well received today, but the first part contains a ton of examples of the kind I mentioned above, so it's useful in that regard.
It's also by no means solely an ancient phenomenon. Throughout the medieval world into the modern world you'll see phrases like "the devil made me do it." It's an escape from self-reflection—you don't know why you hit your friend, ate the last donut, threw a tantrum, but you also don't really recognize yourself as that doer. Clearly, then, it must not be you, but some outside force! I'd even argue that the focus on social or structural elements as origins of actions is a direct continuation of this line of thinking.
In sum, yes, the Greeks allowed for thoughts to come from the gods, but not all thoughts, especially the further (temporally) in Greek society you go.

Thank you, this is a wonderful answer. Would you say that this understanding is common knowledge then? It seems like, implying from your answer, that there are a ton of references that could be given for this concept. So is it more like common knowledge but perhaps people today just don't really make the connection and see it?

@Phillip Do you mean common knowledge among people today or people back then? It's hard to describe something as "common" (common for whom?), but Julian Jaynes' book was reviewed or mentioned by several major scientists, including Richard Dawkins and Daniel Dennett.
